# srcset without high-dpi screen support

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-images, srcset

There is an image tag with srcset attribute that looks like this:

```
<img src="..." 
  srcset="small.jpg 300w, large.jpg 900w"
  sizes="300px" />
```

On normal 1x dpi screen it loads `small.jpg`, but on high DPI screens (such as retina) - it loads `large.jpg`.

Is there some way to make it load `small.jpg` on high DPI screens?

Answer (score 1):

This is how `srcset` works, intentionaly.

If you want to prevent the browser from downloading the relevant image you provide, as your `sizes` value shows that supporting variable viewport widths is not required in your use case, you should use a simple `src` without `srcset`:

```html
<img src="small.jpg" width="300" />
```

But it means you always show the image as 300px wide, and users with screen density above `1dppx` might see a low quality rendering.

Could you explain why you want this to happen?